# How do I unlock Eyeshot in C# console-app

Tags: c#, eyeshot

I’m a student doing a project with the company. As part of this project, I’m developing a console application using eyeshot 2021. I’ve used an activation key before for a WPF project and that application worked fine.

This console-app is created under the same solution but I get the message that I have no license when running BallPivoting.DoWork(). Because this is a console-app I cannot use the class model which requires a Viewport/PresentationFramework. I was therefore wondering how to unlock the application.

I've seen old documentation that says to use UtilityEx.Unlock(), but that does not work for Eyeshot 2021

Thanks for the support!

Comment: Do you have a chance to update to Eyeshot 2022?

Comment: I might. I'll have to ask the company. What in the 2022 version would be the solution?

Edit: oh, i see there is a LicenseManager Class

Comment: The 2022 version comes with sample code how to use the library in a Console application. There is also a new LicenseManager class that you can use to activate the license directly.

Comment: See https://documentation.devdept.com/2022/topic_00000000000056F8.html

Comment: I think it's quite strange how they had the ability to unlock in console applications in earlier version, then remove it, only to add it again.

Comment: I can see that there is an ASP.net WebForms sample in the 2021 version. You could check how the activation is done in that example. Sadly, I can't find a download of the trial version of the 2021 version

Comment: Well, thanks for the help berry hopefully I'm allowed to update.  Else I hope someone might know a way to do it 2021 version

Comment: I've been looking all over for a 2021 trial version/samples, i sent an email to devdept, hopefully they can help. I appreciate you looking into if for me!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250270/discussion-between-nineberry-and-adam-degerman).

Answer (score 3):

In Eyeshot version 2022 you can use the `devDept.LicenseManager.Unlock` method to activate the library.

Use it like this:

```
devDept.LicenseManager.Unlock(typeof(devDept.Eyeshot.Workspace), "YOURACTIVATIONCODEHERE");
```